# Mongodb replica set freeze when removing secondary

Tags: mongodb, freeze

I have a replica set that contains 1 primary, 2 secondaries and 1 arbiter. I want to stop one of the secondaries to perform some maintenance. When i stop the secondary, the replica set notices it is unavailable but all the write/read operations seems to freeze. When i start the secondary again everything works as normal. I have performed this maintenance before without any problems.

The mongodb instances are running on Ubuntu and have tried to stop the intances with sudo service stop and through the mongodb shell using shutdownserver but methods both yields the same result. One thing that i haved changed recently is that the writeconcern is set to majority and i am wondering if this could cause problems when stopping an instance.

I could not see anything sensational in the mongodb log.

I am using mongodb version 2.4.10.

Comment: can you get the result of `db.currentOp(true)` ?

Comment: do you mean after iv'e shut down the secondary?

Comment: Whenever you're getting the locking, so yes, after you shut down the secondary.. It almost sounds like a failover locking issue.. The currentOp will show what its trying to do, thus revealing (hopefully) what is locking up !

Comment: I looked at the results but found nothing noteworthy. I saw that the writeconcern did not have any timeout and after i set the timeout to 500 ms there was some change but it was still not working. I hade writeconcern majority and maybe it freezes becuase the replica set does not realise an unavailable member can't acknowledge a write?